# How to Create a Google Analytics Filter for Multiple Browsers

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-analytics-spam

I would like to filter traffic from multiple browsers from a specific view in Google Analytics. Specifically looking to remove;
Explorer 7,8,9
Firefox 3.628,11,12
Chrome 18.0.1025.168
Safari 5.1

What is the best way to create this? Ideally it would only filter the direct traffic related to the browsers, but the second best solution it to filter the browsers completely. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a series of filters (as they are applied in the order they are created):

```
Filter 1:
Your first filter will build the "<browser>/<browser version>" string:
Custom > Advanced
Field A, Browser, (.*)(
Field B, Browser Version, (.*)
Output, Custom Field 1, $A1:$B1

Filter 2:
Your second filter will filter only the direct traffic:
Custom > Advanced
Field A, Campaign Source, Direct
Field B, Custom Field 1, (.*)
Output, Custom Field 1, Source:$A1, Browser:$B1

Filter 3:
The remaining filters will exclude the different browsers and browser versions that you specify. You may need to create as many of these filters as there are browser and browser version combinations:
Custom > Exclude
Field: Custom Field 1, Source:Direct, Browser:<browser:browser version>
```

where  are your various browser and browser version combos, like "Internet Explorer:7.0", "Firefox:3.628.11, "Firefox:3.628.12", etc.